# Can I use a catchall address if my mail host doesn't support VERP?

Tags: civimail

Our hosting provider does not seem to be able to support VERP on Exim. Is it possible to use a catchall address instead of relying on VERP for bounce processing and forwarding replies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a catchall mailbox to capture [VERP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_envelope_return_path) bounces, and CiviCRM will be able to identify VERP data from this.

CiviCRM has two return paths if you enable Reply Tracking, and unless you somehow used separate domains, you won't have two catchall mailboxes. So using a catchall will probably limit your functionality somewhat here.

You could potentially get CiviCRM to poll first for bounces, move unrecognised emails to a "holding" folder in IMAP, then poll that folder for replies on a second pass ... But it is probably easier to just switch to a mail service which supports VERP, since such mailboxes are widely available ... you'd likely save some effort.

See also [How does Civimail reply tracking and forwarding work?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2314/how-does-civimail-reply-tracking-and-forwarding-work)

Exim can support VERP routing, even if your mail provider may not be willing to provide this.

Comment: Where is the catchall mailbox specified? In the Mail Account settings under Civimail.? I have always used CiviSMTP but my current client does not want to use CiviSMTP so this is the first time I have tried to set it up from scratch. Can you give me an example using two domains?

Comment: To use a catchall you'd configure as for VERP, knowing that bounce+VERP.aabb.CODE.cc@example.org will land in the same mailbox as bounce@example.org due to the catchall rule. Sorry, I can't give an example using two domains, hence the "somehow" in that sentence - speculative only.

Comment: Got it all working. Bounce handling and forwarding. The provider did figure out how to set up VERP